# Why would I want to use the Love Your Enemy trump card?

Tags: resident-evil-7

One of the new banned footage tapes is called "21".  In 21,

> You play [Blackjack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack) against another opponent. However, you bet with your life.  The more hands you lose, the closer you'll come to getting killed until you meet some sort of gruesome death.  Your goal is to kill off your opponent first by winning.

In this game, you can get what are called "trump cards."  These cards can be played on your turn to give you an advantage.  One of the cards is called "Love Your Enemy."  What it does is:

> Your opponent draws the best possible card for them from the deck.

Why would one ever want to use this?  This is essentially helping them lock in a win.  Is there some sort of advantage I'm not seeing with this card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that very specific trump card has a very specific use.

The "Love Your Enemy" trump card forces your opponent to draw the best possible card for them from the deck. If all cards in the deck would result in a bust, the lowest card is drawn instead.

---

Edit: The loading screen hint text for this trump card also reinforces the potential for using it to force an opponent over the target number (21, unless modified by another trump card). Emphasis mine:

> ### Using "Love Your Enemy"
>
> The trump card "Love Your Enemy" helps your opponent out by giving them the best card in the deck.
>
> But on the other hand, **it does mean forcing them to draw a card...**

Resident Evil 7: Biohazard is very good about giving you hints on the loading screen based on why you just lost. The above hint, for instance, will likely pop up in a situation where that trump card would have helped you not lose.

Comment: So I suppose the advantage to this card is if you know how close they are to 21, and know that the cards in the deck would be too high for them, you can use this to make them go bust?

Comment: You can also use it if they're at the target number to force them to go over and bust, as it always makes the opponent draw a card. This is kind of important when you're prevented from drawing cards and you know for a solid fact that the opponent has the target number.